# Is there a way to get a regex to match something and fail resulting in it continuing to match from the end of the failure point?

Tags: .net, regex

I am attempting to match a string that contains something in C++.  Thing is, the item I'm looking for is something that occurs frequently between strings that exist on the same line (I'm looking for `&&`). Because of this, it is causing an undue number of false positives.

I was thinking, would it be possible to find a string, say that the string doesn't contain the looked for item and discard it, continuing from the place it ended the string from.  I'm using the Visual Studio's find function so, the regex is a .NET implementation.

I've tried the following regex, but it still matches between strings on the same line (with the whitespaces removed obviously):

```
(?>
    (?>")
    (?>[^"\r\n"\\&]|\\.)*
    (?>
        (?<AMP>&&)
        (?>[^"\r\n"\\&]|\\.)*
        (?>")
    )
)
(?(AMP)|(?!))
```

Also tried this assuming that variable negative lookbehind might be implemented:

```
(?>
    (?>
        (?<!
            (?>
                (?<-STR>"[^"\r\n]*)
                (?<STR>"[^"\r\n]*)
            )
        )(?(STR)(?!))"
    )
    (?>[^"\r\n"\\&]|\\.)*
    (?>
        (?<AMP>&&)
        (?>[^"\r\n"\\&]|\\.)*
        (?>")
    )
)
(?(AMP)|(?!))
```

Neither worked.  Any other possibilities or is it just beyond the capabilities of a .NET regex?

The following should match:

```
if (strcmp("hello && goodbye", var) == 0)
```

but this should not:

```
if (strcmp("hello", var) == 0 && strcmp("goodbye", var) == 0)
```

Comment: Can you post sample strings and the output you expect?

Comment: @ctwheels, done

Comment: Yes, you can optionally match the part you want to fail. Put it before the part you don't want to fail. Dot-Net doe4snt have skip/fail stuff.

Comment: So you are trying to match inside a double quoted string?

Comment: @revo, yes I am

Comment: @sln, I'm willing to leave that as a false negative atm

Comment: Also, why not span lines ?

Comment: @sln, a double quoted item that spans lines in C++ is rare atm, and is non-existent in the codebase I'm looking at.

Comment: @sln, I'd consider that as a positive

Comment: @sln, because I don't care about the comments atm.  They would be rare enough to not be an issue.

Comment: Do you guess much of such occurrences will exist in one document? I mean number of `&&`s.

Comment: @revo, sorry, I don't understand what you meant.  There are many `&&` as these are C++ source files.

Comment: Hey @sln, I came back to see if you had updated your answer with a formatted explanation, but you deleted it.  Why?

Comment: @sln As this site isn't just for me, and your answer was in the regex variant that was asked for, I would have selected yours for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had given up and went to perl style regexes using the command line:

```sh
grep -RnP --color --include="*.h" --include="*.cpp" '_regex_here_'
```

with the regex being equivalent to the following with the whitespaces removed:

```
(?>
    (?>")                               (?# match first ")
    (?>[^"\r\n"\\&]|\\.)*               (?# match till eol, " or &)
    (?>
            (?>
                (?>
                    (?<AMP>\&\&)        (?# found &&, store in capture group AMP)
                |
                    (?>\&)(?!\&)
                )+                      (?# match single or double &&)
                (?>[^"\r\n"\\&]|\\.)*   (?# match till eol, " or &)
            )+                          (?# one or more)
            (?>")                       (?# match last ")
        |
            (?>[^"\r\n"\\&]|\\.)*       (?# match till eol, " or &)
            (?>")                       (?# match last ")
            (*SKIP)                     (?# when fail, start from here)
            (*FAIL)                     (?# fail)
    )
)
(?(<AMP>)|(?*FAIL))                     (?# if AMP capture group was not set, then fail)
```